# How can i change whitespace color in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I don't want my whitespace colored like in the below screenshot.

I have the default `whitespace-mode` turned off.

How can I disable this highlighting?

[image: about emacs whitespace]

Comment: Move your cursor onto the coloured whitespace and do `C-u C-x =` (`M-x what-cursor-position`). This will list lots of information, including the `face`, which should give us a clue what's happening.

Comment: Try running emacs with `emacs -Q` and see what it looks like. This will load it without any customizations. It should not look like your picture by default. There is almost certainly something strange in the config files.

Comment: "Char: SPC (32, #o40, #x20) point=21 of 956 (2%) column=5" there is no face informations

Comment: @natrollus, sorry, my `M-x` example is missing its prefix. `C-u M-x what-cursor-position`. Running without the `C-u` gives what you typed above; with `C-u` it should give much more.

Comment: @Tyler but i use python mode,and auto-completions rope,elpy etc..

Comment: That's the point. @Tyler is suggesting that we disable all that other stuff for now, to help figure out what's causing this.

Comment: This is just for debugging your problem. Once we fix it you can use your .emacs again! Once we can confirm the problem is in your .emacs, you can start looking in there to find the cause.

Comment: @Chris thanks this may help me,getting some info like: highlight-indent-face

Comment: @Tyler yes this shown after python mode,no problem other file types .java,.xml etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the name of the face `highlight-indent-face`, it looks like this is being caused by [`highlight-indentation-mode` or `highlight-indentation-current-column-mode`](https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs/), both provided by the same extension.

Check `C-x m` to see which one is turned on.

Now you can turn it off (more likely stop turning it on automatically in your configuration).

Comment: thanks for help @Chris,if this mode turned on causes whitespace

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've managed to turn on `whitespace-mode`. Turn it off with `M-x whitespace-mode`.

It's not turned on by default, so if it's always on when you start Emacs, check your `.emacs` file to see if the command shows up in there.

Comment: yes i try this solution,but when do whitespace-mode turnoff end of all lines "$",and whitespace gone

Comment: and default `whitespace-mode`turned off

Comment: As @Tyler said, start with `emacs -Q`. Does that give you the behavior you want? If no, describe what the difference is. If yes, then bisect your init file recursively until you discover which part of it is removing the `emacs -Q` behavior that you want.

Comment: thanks @Tyler emacs -Q mode turned off everything,autocompletions and highlights..

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. The important thing is: did it turn off the whitespace highlighting that you are having problems with??